# Virtual host in apache on Mint VM doesn't work

Tags: apache, drupal, virtualbox, linux-mint

I have Apache running on a Mint VM on a Windows 8 host so I can use the VM for Drupal development.  I created a VirtualHost entry in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` so I can use `www.mysite.dev` as a development URL, and I set up the `hosts` files on the guest host machines.  The target platform for deployment is Acquia, in case that's relevant.

The problem I'm having is that, when use a browser in the guest to go to `http://www.mysite.dev/`, I get my site, but when I access `http://www.mysite.dev/any-non-root-path`, I get a 404.  Also, when I use a browser on the host to go to `http://www.mysite.dev`, I instead get the Apache default home page.

In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on the guest, I have:

```
<VirtualHost www.mysite.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/docroot/
    ServerName www.mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/hosts` on the guest, I have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vm-name
127.0.0.1       www.my-site.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

In `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on the host, I have

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.44.44   www.drupal7.dev 
192.168.44.45   www.mysite.dev
```

192.168.44.45 is the IP address of the VM on the host-only network I created in VirtualBox.  (The 192.168.44.44 is from when I was trying Vagrant, but the shared folder performance was too slow.  I figured instead of learning Vagrant just to muck around, I might as well skip straight to the muck!)

I suspect the two issues I'm having are related.  So my question is this: how can I resolve these two issues so I get the content I want both while browsing from the host and while browsing from the guest?

Thanks!

**edit** The specific error I was getting for the path issue was `The requested URL [...] was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New Answer**:  This answer solves both problems.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.44.45 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site-name
    ServerName www.site-name.dev
    <Directory "/var/www/html/site-name/docroot/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So that's the answer, Mr. Spock!

**Original Answer**  So a fresh look Monday morning got me part of the answer.  I guess this is really two questions.

The fix to the non-root URL was to add a directory element.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/1038.

```
<VirtualHost www.site-name.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site-name
    ServerName www.site-name.dev
    <Directory "/var/www/html/site-name/docroot/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm still looking into the other part.